# Prolog recursive function not behaving as expected

Tags: recursion, prolog, fibonacci, trace

I'm trying to implement the recursive version of the Fibonacci sequence in Prolog. Below is the code:

```
fib(0,F) :- F is 0.
fib(1,F) :- F is 1.
fib(N,F) :- N > 1,
AA is (N - 1),
BB is (N - 2),
fib(AA,CC),
fib(BB,DD),
RR is (CC + DD),
F == RR,
F is RR.
```

The problem is that it's not behaving as I logically expect it to. When I use `trace` to call fib(3,2), I get the following lines:

```
   Call: (7) fib(3, 2) ? creep
   Call: (8) 3>1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 3>1 ? creep
   Call: (8) _G2569 is 3+ -1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 2 is 3+ -1 ? creep
   Call: (8) _G2572 is 3+ -2 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 1 is 3+ -2 ? creep
   Call: (8) fib(2, _G2573) ? creep
   Call: (9) 2>1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 2>1 ? creep
   Call: (9) _G2575 is 2+ -1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 2+ -1 ? creep
   Call: (9) _G2578 is 2+ -2 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 0 is 2+ -2 ? creep
   Call: (9) fib(1, _G2579) ? creep
   Call: (10) _G2578 is 1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 1 is 1 ? creep
```

What catches my attention is the last call, Call: (10), which says "_G2578 is 1 ?", even though I'm calling fib(1, _G2579). My expectation is that it's _G2579 that's going to be changed, but that does not appear to be the case. I need to find out why because I highly suspect that this is why fib(3,2) is returning false instead of true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, if I'm not wrong, is in

```
F == R
```

that check if `F` (a newly introduced term without a value) is equal to `R`.

If you change it in

```
F = R
```

so unifing `F` with `R` (an in redundant following `F is R`), your `fib/2` should work.

But I propose you some semplification.

(1) the terminale case `fib(0,F) :- F is 0.` is good but you can write it as

```
fib(0,0).
```

(2) same semplification for the other terminal case: you can write it as

```
fib(1,1).
```

(3) in the general clause, you don't need two different variables `F` and `RR` with the same (unified) value; you can use only `F` in the following way

```
fib(N,F) :-
  N > 1,
  AA is (N - 1),
  BB is (N - 2),
  fib(AA,CC),
  fib(BB,DD),
  F is (CC + DD).
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested changes! After implementing the code you wrote in (3) in my own program, the behavior I initially expected has now been fulfilled. It returns true in all cases where F is exactly the Nth fibonacci number, and only in those cases.